# How to export lambda function zip

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In older aws lambda UI there was an option to export function zip, but after the update the option is not there.

[image]

Comment: What does the button under the pull down you're showing say?

Answer (score 0):

The button says "Download Function" and is now located right below the Action menu.

[image]